# How to pass an error details in PL/SQL exception propagation without a package state?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Currently I'm using the following pattern to record error details in PL/SQL exception propagation. Please see the commented code below for the details. I'm happy with it as the error handling code doesn't clutter the whole code base and all the details why an error was triggered can be recorded.

Unfortunately there is an unwanted side-effect of package state introduced by `v_error` variable.

*How I can pass an error detail information in PL/SQL exception propagation without introducing a package state ?* (I want to eliminate package state to make deployment easier.)

Using different exceptions like `rule_2_failure_ex` and `rule_3_failure_ex` is not the solution I'm looking for as

1. there is no need to handle the error conditions differently
2. for troubleshooting it is very important to be able to record arbitrary information

(I'm already using a logging so the error condition information is available, but it's not in "the right place".)

I'm looking for Oracle 11g solution but 12c solution (if different than in 11g) is also welcome as one day I might end working with 12c too (personally I don't care about 10g).

```
-- this is a simplied example to address to question only
create or replace package so50 is
  procedure run(p_num in number);
end;
/
show errors

create or replace package body so50 is
  processing_failure_ex exception;

  -- package state that I'd like to eliminate
  v_error varchar2(32767);

  -- in reality the processing and details are more complex
  procedure p3(p_num in number) is
  begin
    if p_num = 3
    then
      -- it's important to be able to record arbitrary information at this point
      v_error := 'Failed to process rule 3: (p_num = ' || p_num || ')';
      raise processing_failure_ex;
    end if;
  end;

  -- the comments on p3 apply
  procedure p2(p_num in number) is
  begin
    if p_num = 2
    then
      v_error := 'Failed to process rule 2: (p_num = ' || p_num || ')';
      raise processing_failure_ex;
    end if;
  end;

  procedure p1(p_num in number) is
  begin
    p2(p_num);
    p3(p_num);
  exception
    when others then
      v_error := v_error
        || ' Additional details of failure.';
      raise;
  end;

  procedure run(p_num in number) is
  begin
    v_error := null;
    begin
      p1(p_num);
    exception
      when processing_failure_ex then
        -- in reality an error recovery will be tried first and only then
        -- the error will be forwarded to a monitoring framework that will
        -- raise an alert for human action
        dbms_output.put_line('Error details: ' || v_error);
        raise;
    end;
  exception
    when others then
      -- out of the scope of the question
      raise;
  end;
end;
/
show errors
```

Comment: At the moment this prints the 'Error details: ' line and then gets ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception, if called with a value of 1 or 2 anyway. You're essentially trying to see the 'Error details' string in the exception stack trace?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, pretty much so. IMO `raise_application_error` requires unnecessary extra boilerplate I'd like to avoid. But that's not always possible with PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`raise_application_error`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS99960) with an error code tied to your exception:

```
create or replace package body so50 is
  processing_failure_ex exception;
  pragma exception_init(processing_failure_ex, -20999);
```

And raise with the message you want:

```
    raise_application_error(-20999,
      'Failed to process rule 3: (p_num = ' || p_num || ')', true);
```

When you want to store the whole stack you can use [`dbms_utility.format_error_stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_util.htm#ARPLS73242):

```
    dbms_output.put_line('Error details:');
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
```

So removing `v_error` altogether:

```
create or replace package so50 is
  procedure run(p_num in number);
end;
/

create or replace package body so50 is
  processing_failure_ex exception;
  pragma exception_init(processing_failure_ex, -20999);

  -- in reality the processing and details are more complex
  procedure p3(p_num in number) is
  begin
    if p_num = 3
    then
      -- it's important to be able to record arbitrary information at this point
        raise_application_error(-20999,
          'Failed to process rule 3: (p_num = ' || p_num || ')', true);
    end if;
  end;

  -- the comments on p3 apply
  procedure p2(p_num in number) is
  begin
    if p_num = 2
    then
        raise_application_error(-20999,
          'Failed to process rule 2: (p_num = ' || p_num || ')', true);
    end if;
  end;

  procedure p1(p_num in number) is
  begin
    p2(p_num);
    p3(p_num);
  exception
    when others then
      raise_application_error(-20999,
        'Additional details of failure', true);
  end;

  procedure run(p_num in number) is
  begin
    begin
      p1(p_num);
    exception
      when processing_failure_ex then
        -- in reality an error recovery will be tried first and only then
        -- the error will be forwarded to a monitoring framework that will
        -- raise an alert for human action
        dbms_output.put_line('Error details:');
        dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
        raise;
    end;
  exception
    when others then
      -- out of the scope of the question
      raise;
  end;
end;
/
```

Calling that gets:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec so50.run(1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec so50.run(2);

ORA-20999: Additional details of failure
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.SO50", line 42
ORA-20999: Failed to process rule 2: (p_num = 2)
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.SO50", line 64
ORA-06512: at line 1

Error details:
ORA-20999: Additional details of failure
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.SO50", line 42
ORA-20999: Failed to process rule 2: (p_num = 2)

SQL> exec so50.run(3);

ORA-20999: Additional details of failure
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.SO50", line 42
ORA-20999: Failed to process rule 3: (p_num = 3)
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.SO50", line 64
ORA-06512: at line 1

Error details:
ORA-20999: Additional details of failure
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.SO50", line 42
ORA-20999: Failed to process rule 3: (p_num = 3)
```

In both cases the stack trace before the 'Error details:' is coming from the final out-of-scope raise; if that was temporarily squashed (just for a demo, not suggesting you really squash it!) you'd just see:

```
SQL> exec so50.run(3);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Error details:
ORA-20999: Additional details of failure
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.SO50", line 42
ORA-20999: Failed to process rule 3: (p_num = 3)
```

You can use different exception numbers for the various procedures and scenarios of course, I've just used a common one to simplify things for now. They only need to be named (tied with a name via a pragma) if you want to catch them by name. And if you do you could have all the exceptions defined in one place.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution based on @AlexPoole answer:

**Exception Package**

```
-- encapsulates the uglyness to keep calling code clean
create or replace package so50_ex is
  -- exception type and error code reserved for this purpose only
  general_ex exception;
  general_ex_code constant number := -20999;
  pragma exception_init(general_ex, -20999);

  procedure raise(p_msg in varchar2, p_ex_code in number default -20999);

  function full_error_stack return varchar2;
end;
/
show errors

create or replace package body so50_ex is
  procedure raise(p_msg in varchar2, p_ex_code in number default -20999) is
  begin
    raise_application_error(p_ex_code,
                            substrb(p_msg, 1, 2048),
                            true);
  end;

  function full_error_stack return varchar2 as
    -- will always fit to buffer as format_error_stack returns 2000 bytes at
    -- maximum
    v_stack varchar2(32767) := dbms_utility.format_error_stack;
  begin
    -- might not fit to buffer as format_error_backtrace return length is not
    -- limited
    v_stack := v_stack ||
      substrb(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace, 1, 30767);
    return v_stack;
  end;
end;
/
show errors
```

**Usage Example**

```
create or replace package so50 is
  -- a user can always have his own exceptions
  processing_failure_ex exception;
  processing_failure_ex_code constant number := -20100;
  pragma exception_init(processing_failure_ex, -20100);

  procedure run(p_num in number);
end;
/
show errors

create or replace package body so50 is
  procedure p3(p_num in number) is
  begin
    if p_num = 3
    then
      -- use specific exception
      so50_ex.raise('Failed to process rule 3: (p_num = ' || p_num || ')',
                    processing_failure_ex_code);
    end if;
  end;

  procedure p2(p_num in number) is
  begin
    if p_num = 2
    then
      -- use default exception
      so50_ex.raise('Failed to process rule 2: (p_num = ' || p_num || ')');
    end if;
  end;

  procedure p1(p_num in number) is
  begin
    p2(p_num);
    p3(p_num);
  exception
    when processing_failure_ex then
      dbms_output.put_line('ERROR RECOVERED SUCCESFULLY.');
      dbms_output.put_line('DETAILS:');
      dbms_output.put_line(so50_ex.full_error_stack);
    when others then
      so50_ex.raise('Additional details of failure.');
  end;

  procedure run(p_num in number) is
  begin
    p1(p_num);
  exception
    when others then
      dbms_output.put_line('EXCEPTION: ' || so50_ex.full_error_stack);
      raise;
  end;
end;
/
show errors
```